# How can I correct missing parenthesis expression?

Tags: powershell, screenshot

I am currently taking an intro class for Information Technology and we are working in PowerShell this week.

We were provided with a Code that will take screenshots and have to do the rest of our assignment based on said code.
Now my problem is that I insert the code exactly as it was in our assignment but for some reason I am getting an Error code. And unfortunately my teacher is not responding so I am stuck.

The line that is giving me the Error is

```
-for($i = 1; $i -le 1000; $i++)  {...}
```

I will attach a picture of the whole code with the Error message. I tried everything I could think of to fix it myself so I can finish my assignment but I am lost.

[Code with Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0yMw.png)

I tried to replace the semicolons with colons and that actually removes the Error message and makes it seem like the program is running but it does not give me any screenshots

Comment: Why is there a dash in front of `for`?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714). Copy and paste everything as text in proper format

Comment: @phuclv With your editing of the question you corrected the actual error from the question. As you can see in the screenshot the hyphen was not just a typo here in SO.

Comment: @Olaf sorry I thought that it was a typo in the question. Updated it

Comment: @phuclv  That's what I thought. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop has a leading hyphen - before the for loop, which is not valid syntax. Try removing the hyphen and see what you get.

```
for($i = 1; $i -le 1000; $i++) {...}
```

Additionally, removing the semicolons giving you a better output will be a red herring.
PowerShell and many other languages have specific syntax requirements for creating for loops:

```
for (initialisation; condition; increment) {
    # code to execute
}
```

The semicolons are essential to separate these parts. Replacing them with colons would break the structure of the for loop and result in a syntax error.
The documentation for this can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_for?view=powershell-7.3), but in essence, the purpose of each part is as follows:

Initialisation: This is executed once at the beginning of the loop to initialise the incrementer variable. e.g. $i is initialised as 1.

Condition: This is checked before each iteration of the loop. If the condition is true, the loop continues; if false, the loop exits.

Increment: This is executed after each iteration of the loop. e.g., $i++ increments the value of $i by 1.